# lxsession/LXDE/autostart is not running my script?

Tags: midori, startx

My custom script to start midori in fullscreen browser is not loading when the pi boots. I want it to run when the desktop loads.

I call the script from `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart`

by using the code

`@sh /home/pi/startMidori`

startMidori is the script I made which contains;

`#!/bin/sh
midori -e Fullscreen -a http://google.com`

I can run the script from terminal as `sh startMidori` and it runs as expected without any issues, any idea what is going on?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RPi Jessie not working ?

I think you want to use the autostart here:

```
/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

or:

```
~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

not here:

```
/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart
```

...at least with the default Raspbian setup of LXDE.

Comment: funny thing is, left it alone over the weekend, wifi stopped working and now the auto start into midori isn't working.. I've had so many problems with raspberry pi it's getting a bit silly now

Comment: This didn't work for me... it took me an hour or so to figure out it uses `~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`